# как удалить супер пользователя

Tags: ubuntu

создал  пользователя с правами su (на свою голову)
создал его так `sudo su - wp-user` а также ему папочку подарил `sudo chown -R wp-user:wp-user /var/www/html`
, удалить не получается также и директорию которую он у меня (рута ) отнял также не выходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `sudo chown -R root:root /var/www/html` не работает что ли?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да я так сделал но мусор ввиде не нужного пользователя появился

Comment: Ну приведённая команда точно не создаёт пользователя, так что он уже был